# Dropdown dont work Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, dropdown

So I want to make a dropdown using Bootstrap 4 for my Spring MVC Aplication.
I'm also using Thymeleaf template engine.
I 'imported' popper.js and jQuery in my html page.Also I have  included Bootstraps's Css and Javascript to static direcotory as separate files in my project

```
 <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

And it's still not working.
Here the full code of my html page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Footer</title>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="footer">
        <div>
            <a  th:href="@{/notebook/add}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button">Add Note</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Sort</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Date_ASC')}">Date Ascending</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Date_DESC')}">Date Descending</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Done')}">Done</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Not_Done')}">Not Done</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the drop-down to work, you must load the following 3 JavaScript files

**and load them in that particular order** (first jQuery, then popper.js and then bootstrap.js):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include Bootstrap's CSS and Javascript files in order for it to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I have already included Bootstraps's Css and Javascript to static direcotory as separate files in my project

Comment: They're not referenced in your HTML though. You need to actually load those files in using the tags I provided in my answer. Check out this jsfiddle where it works as you want: https://jsfiddle.net/yowbk9ar/2/

Answer (score 0):

Updated your snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="footer">
        <div>
            <a  th:href="@{/notebook/add}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button">Add Note</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Sort</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Date_ASC')}">Date Ascending</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Date_DESC')}">Date Descending</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Done')}">Done</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/notebook/sort(method='Not_Done')}">Not Done</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will helps you